# finding the position of an element in a nested list

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

just seeing if anyone can help me on my mission as I'm a little stuck. I'm trying to find all the positions of a specific nested element in multiple list. here's a diagram to try and better explain where everything is.

```
data = [['name', 'city', 'height']]
```

there are multiple of these lists of ['name', 'city', 'height'] in this data. I'm trying to shorten the list down to a city inputted by the user which will then find the average height and list the persons name closest to that average height.

I can get just the whole elements position but not the position in the nested list. along with the average height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `enumerate()` to iterate over the list with its indexes. Then you can save the matching indexes in a list.

```
indexes = [i for i, (name, city, height) in enumerate(data) if city == search_city]
```

But it's not clear that you actually need the indexes. Just use the list comprehension to filter down to that city.

```
matches = [el for el in data if el[1] == search_city]
avg_height = sum(el[2] for el in matches) / len(matches)
```